# Why can't I pass in a regular value to a function call that takes in a pointer?

Tags: c++, parameter-passing

When I try to compile my code I get an error

> cannot convert 'float' to 'const float*'.

I was thinking that maybe I needed to be passing in a `const` but it shouldn't matter.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

static float foo(const float *pArray,int n);

int main() {
    foo(3.145f,5);
    return 0;
}

static float foo(const float *pArray,int n)
{
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: At the risk of sounding obvious, it's because a float is not a pointer to float.

Comment: `3.145f` is not an array or pointer, it is just a `float`

Comment: @NathanOliver I don't see how *pArray would need to be an array though. If it were an array wouldnt we see something like pArray[5] etc. What I'm trying to say is that there is no indication that pArray is an array though the name states it is but how would it be obvious though?

Comment: @Darraptor; it's a pointer, and you have indicated that it's a pointer to (first item of) an array. You can pass a pointer to a single `float` if you want. Or a nullpointer.

Comment: You can make it "obvious" by passing a `std::array` or `std::vector` instead of raw pointers (which don't distinguish the use cases on their own)

Comment: I haven't tried running the code on my computers, but agree with what people have said on here that the float isn't a pointer to anything. Also I noticed you're only returning 0 from your function. Did you mean to do that?

Comment: yes but that is beside the point because I just wanted to understand with passing in parameters

Answer (score 2):

you have to pass a pointer

```
float number=3.145;
foo(&number,n);
```

Comment: Best to use `float number= 3.145f;` as `3.145` is a double literal while `3.145f` is a float literal.

Comment: @NathanOliver but shouldnt 3.145 become a float because even though its originally a double, we cast it as a float or am I missing something here?

Comment: @Darraptor, you'll quickly learn the two are not the same when you try to use any sort of templated code with literals.

Comment: @Darraptor Yes it will convert but it should issue a narrowing conversion diagnostic.  We can stop that by explicitly stating our intent by making it a float literal.

Comment: @NathanOliver If I do something like double call_me_float=2.00f; would it come out to be a double?

Comment: @Darraptor Yes and it a widening conversion which will never have any surprises since a double contains all values that a float does.

Answer (score 0):

C++ is a statically typed and compiled language. That means that the types of any arguments in a function call must, at compile time, be known and match those of the function declaration.

An exact match is not required: conversions are allowed, but there is no conversion from a `float` to a `const float*`, i.e. from a floating-point number to a memory address.

In some older code, or some C code, values are passed by pointer. That is, instead of passing the value (of the floating-point number in this case), the memory address of where this number is stored is passed. To use such functions with intermediate results or literals, one must first store the value in some variable and then take the address of that variable to pass as function argument:

```
void foo(const float*);   // function declaration
foo(&(3.1415));           // ERROR: cannot take address of literal
float tmp = 3.1415;       // store number in variable
foo(&tmp);                // pass address of variable to function
```